# How can I fix the extra space I am getting when giving color to an equation in an itemize environment?

Tags: spacing, color, itemize

I am trying to be able to color math that I am using within an itemize environment. Below is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
    \color{red}
    \[
        y=x^2
    \]
    \color{black}
\item
    Blah blah blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

If I remove the `\color` commands, I get:

[image]

So for whatever reason, there is additional space between the bullets when I do the color stuff. I have tried using `\bgroup` and `\egroup` rather than changing the color back with `\color{black}`, and did not have luck getting rid of that extra space. Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: My original example out some things in the sake of being minimal. The code and image below are more representative of the usage I am looking for. In particular, I would strongly prefer to not have to set up colors both outside of and inside of the math mode, as that seems rather clunky to fix a spacing issue.

EDIT 2: To clarify, the problem that remains is that the spacing after the equation is larger than it would be without the color stuff.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
    A few things I would like to say.
    \color{red}
    Some text here to say some things about the equation.
    \[
        y=x^2
    \]
    \color{black}
\item
    Blah blah blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: remove the \color{black}  and put the red color inside the equation?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately not ideal for my use case. I've added an edit to my question to be more specific.

Comment: Are you interested in only one color, say red as in the example, for your colored paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, I am only looking to use one color in my paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation grfguide writes:

> There is a different type of problem that will occur for all drivers. Due to certain
> technical difficulties, it is possible that at points where the colour changes, the
> spacing is affected.

[image]

color commands insert whatsits and in certain places this is quite a pain. So if possible try to insert color changes in paragraphs. For your example, e.g. in the next item. You will have to adapt the color of the bullet too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
    A few things I would like to say.
    
    \color{red}Some text here to say some things about the equation.
    \[
        y=x^2
    \]
\item[\textcolor{black}{\labelitemi}]
    \leavevmode\color{black}Blah blah blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

But `grfguide` is a bit wrong in one place: the problem doesn't exist for *all* drivers. With `lualatex` you could use the luacolor package and there your example would work without problems:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
    A few things I would like to say.
    \color{red}Some text here to say some things about the equation.
    \[
        y=x^2
    \]\color{black}
\item
    Blah blah blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second response was exactly what I was looking for, nice and clean without having to do a bunch of stuff manually everywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution with `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$ \color{red}\displaystyle y=x^2$}
\item Blah blah blah.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: to obtain the same result with  `\[ \]`, you can load `nccmath` and use this code:

```
\item \leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\useshortskip\[ \color{red}y=x^2 \]
```

Comment: you probably want `\displaystyle`

Comment: That' right. I didn't think of it because  it wasn't necessary with this formula. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: even here you'll get a higher superscript

Comment: I didn't know that! I'll change the screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am specifically looking for a method that works with `\[ ... \]` and as far as I can tell with briefly playing around, this does not seem to work.

Edit: To elaborate, in my use case, I often have larger equations introduced by text, so an out-of-line equation is preferable.

Comment: Don't you want a displayed equation without vertical spacing? (I mean, if it  is multilined, starting on the same line as the itemize bullet).

Comment: @Bernard I want it to be separate from the itemized bullet. I edited the original question to be reflect that desire, sorry for the lack of specificity.

Comment: I don't see very well what the problem is in your edit. You don't want to have to type `\color{black}`  each time?

Comment: @Bernard the problem is that the spacing is not "normal", i.e. there is more space after the equation than there normally would be without the color stuff.

Comment: Yes, it adds `belowdisplayskip`. That's why I posted as solution based on  `\makebox[\linewidth]{$... $}`.

Comment: Is there a way to make changing the color not add ````belowdisplayskip```` afterward? Additionally, I'm not looking for a way to specifically use ````\[  ...  \]````, I just want to match the spacing (without having to set the color both inside and outside of the equation). As far as I can tell, none of the things you have said do that.

Comment: @AbeSchulte:  If you want the spacing *before* the equation, and  the normal spacing between items after the equation, you can add the former *before*: `\item \leavevmode\vspace{abovedisplayskip}\makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle y=x^2.$}`. The supplementary spacing is *not* due to  the use of `\color`, but to using a displaystyle environment.